# Testing https API endpoint on localhost against a 3rd party app

Tags: security, ssl, https, certificate, localhost

I'm completely new to https and testing on localhost - please help!

### What I'm doing

I'm trying to have a 3rd party app call my REST API endpoint, `https://localhost:4000/test`. This 3rd party only supports connections via `https`.

### Problem

I'm trying to test this integration on `localhost`. To do this, I created a self-signed certificate using openssl. When this 3rd party service calls my endpoint, `https://localhost:4000/test`, it returns an error "Operation failed: Service is unreachable". On the docs, the error description is:

`Error 400301: May be returned when executing Extensions, and the extension point did not respond.`

**Theory 1:** The 3rd party doesn't trust my self-signed certificate (vs one from `letsencrypt`).

Clue #1: postman also didn't like my certificate and gave this error. I could only get it working by disabling the "SSL Validation" flag in Postman.

Clue #2: I put logs when my `/test` endpoint gets called on my server. But when the 3rd party triggers the event to call my API, nothing gets logged. It seems like they can't even start a connection to my server.

[image]

**Theory 2:** It doesn't support connections to localhost, only to endpoints deployed on the internet. Not sure how to test this theory other than actually deploying my API on the internet.

#### node.js snippet

```js
https
  .createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync("./my-private.key"),
      cert: fs.readFileSync("./my-certificate.crt"),
      passphrase: "secret",
    },
    app
  )
  .listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on https://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
  });
```

#### Command I used to sign my certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in my-request.csr -signkey my-private.key -out my-certificate.crt
```

One thing I noticed is that when I connect to `https://localhost:4000` from Firefox, it tells me I'm not connected securely. Is this because the certificate is not signed by a 3rd party that the browser recognizes? How do I make this error go away?

[image]

Comment: What URL is the third party calling? localhost?

Comment: @MarekPuchalski yes, it's calling `https://localhost:4000/test`

Comment: The third party you are talking about. Is this on the same server as your app or somewhere else?

Comment: @MarekPuchalski It's on a different server, I don't have visibility/control over it. I can only trigger their service to call my endpoint.

Comment: When a computer calls `localhost`, it calls a loopback to itself. No other computer will see this request, only the one calling.

Comment: Your machine must be visible to the third party due to e.g. having a public IP address. It will not work when we work inside your private network behind a NAT. You would have to open ports on the router and the router itself would need to be reachable too.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski Thanks for the clarification, Marek. So basically I need to deploy my API to the internet so that this service can call it - there's no way to test this with `localhost`?

Comment: Yes. This might be the easiest thing to do without going deeper into the stuff of what, why and how you are doing.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski OK. This answers my question, thank you Marek!!